# Lendo dados de um Json com php

Tags: php

Bom eu recebo o seguinte JSON via post:

```
string '{
"pedidos": [{
    "feito_data": "2017-08-07",
    "valor": 40.0
}]
}' (length=265)
```

Com o php eu trato os dados assim:

```
// Recebe dados do JSON
$mix = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'json', FILTER_DEFAULT);

// Decodifica json
$jsonObj = json_decode($mix);

// Faz o parsing da string, criando o array
$mix = $jsonObj->pedidos;

// Navega pelos elementos do array, e cadastra novos clientes
foreach ($mix as $c) {

    echo $c->feito_data;
}
```

Bom o que eu quero fazer é o seguinte, como o json só vai me mandar 1 resultado eu não preciso usar o `foreach` e não preciso dar um nome para o objeto como `pedidos`.

Minha dúvida é como receber os dados assim `$c->feito_data`?

Comment: Fez um var_dump no $aqui eu coloco o post com o json para ter certeza que os dados vieram como você esta imaginando ?

Comment: Vou fazer agora é editar a pergunta ok.

Comment: tenho certeza que o `$aqui` esta vindo mal, fiz o teste agora aqui, e tudo dá certinho.

Comment: A Sintaxe esta correta, porém realmente o retorno do $aqui deve estar errada.

Comment: Não entendi o problema, se for usar o `foreach` basta um `echo $c` para imprimir o valor.

Comment: Qual o retorno de `var_dump($mix)`?

Comment: Como eu faço para não precisar colocar um nome no son? tipo `$mix = $jsonObj->pedidos;`

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade já adicionei o retorno na pergunta.

Comment: Você quer pegar apenas a primeira ocorrência de `feito_data`? Pois a sua chave `pedidos` é um array.

Comment: Isso mesmo minha chave `pedidos` é um array, porém sempre vai conter apenas 1 resultado, quero pegar o valor sem precisar do`foreach`

Comment: Basta pegar desta forma: $feitoData = $jsonObj->pedidos[0]->feito_data ou alterar seu json para que retorne sempre um objeto sem estar dentro do array.

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt vlw erra isso mesmo que eu queria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso queira obter apenas a primeira ocorrência, você pode acessar o índice do primeiro elemento do `array`:

```
echo $jsonObj->pedidos[0]->feito_data;
```

Como a chave `pedidos` é um `array`, você terá de iterar sobre ele para acessar outros registros.

@edit

Você também pode utilizar a função [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), que irá apontar para o primeiro elemento do `array`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
reset($jsonObject->pedidos)->feito_data
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/867vmL)

Answer (score 3):

A tua chave `pedidos` é um array, pelo que entendi so vai conter 1 elemento então faz o seguinte acessa apenas o 1 elemento

```
$jsonObj->pedidos[0]->feito_data;
```